# Avoid black-holed request after back button CakePHP2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

I have noticed the form is black-holed when I use `Security` Component at CakePHP2.2 and a user clicks on the back browser button to return to a form after having clicked on other link of the site.

For example:

> home
>
> click on **new post** link (but not posting)
>
> click on **news**
>
> back to **new post**
>
> Trying to post ---> **BLACK-HOLED!!**

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't because the idea is to avoid form manipulation. Each form gets a unique hash generated when it is rendered the first time. This hash is checked server side when the form is submitted. The 2nd time you try to submit the form when you hit the submit button the hash is not longer valid. You can disable the post security check for that action but I would not sacrifice security for that.

Comment: Yeah, i know how tokens works but I was just wondering if there's any way to avoid this behavior. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can disable the security check on post data but as I said, I would not recommend that. Maybe better show a warning to the user that he can not resubmit the form or something?

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is a way. You can disable browser caching for the page with form so when you hit the back button, whole new page is loaded from server with new hashes.

```
$this->response->disableCache();
```

just put it into your Controller method.